# Simplification of Gamma functions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions

I am having some trouble simplifying some Gamma functions. I have a large expression in which some combinations of Gamma functions appear, that can be simplified, but applying `FullSimplify` won't give the desired result.

As an example, this combination appears:

```
(111 Gamma[5/4]^3)/(-96 Gamma[9/4]^3 + 40 Gamma[5/4]^2 Gamma[13/4])
```

after applying `FullSimplify`,

```
FullSimplify[(111 Gamma[5/4]^3)/(-96 Gamma[9/4]^3 + 40 Gamma[5/4]^2 Gamma[13/4])]

(* (111 Gamma[5/4]^3)/(-96 Gamma[9/4]^3 + 40 Gamma[5/4]^2 Gamma[13/4]) *)
```

Although, if I consider the inverse expression, the simplification goes well,

```
FullSimplify[(-96 Gamma[9/4]^3 + 40 Gamma[5/4]^2 Gamma[13/4])/(111 Gamma[5/4]^3)]

(* -(25/37) *)
```

I guess that this is due to the sum in the numerator, so the fraction can be expanded, then Mathematica recognises the to ratios of Gamma functions and simplify them separatedly.

I have tried with `FunctionExpand`, `Expand`, `Apart`... and didn't get any result. Any advice?

Comment: Something like:  `FullSimplify[(111 Gamma[5/4]^3)/(-96 Gamma[9/4]^3 + 
     40 Gamma[5/4]^2 Gamma[13/4])] //. {Gamma[x_] /; 
    x > 1 -> (x - 1) Gamma[x - 1]}`.  (Using a conditional rule.)  And actually for this example `FullSimplify[]` is not needed to get the desired answer.

Comment: That totally solved it! Maybe you should wirte it as an answer to close the question.

Comment: Or `1/FullSimplify[1/expr]`

Comment: @BobHanlon the problem is that this is not an isolated expression, so I cannot invert it as you suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rules are your friends.  (And I should use them more myself.)  Here's a conditional rule that should help:

```
gamRule = {Gamma[x_] /; x > 1 -> (x - 1) Gamma[x - 1]};

(111 Gamma[5/4]^3)/(-96 Gamma[9/4]^3 + 40 Gamma[5/4]^2 Gamma[13/4]) //. gamRule
(* -(37/25) *)
```

In this particular example, `FullSimplify` is not needed but the use of `//.` (`ReplaceRepeated`) rather than just `/.` (`ReplaceAll`) is needed.

Comment: A generalization: `(111 Gamma[5/4]^3)/(-96 Gamma[9/4]^3 + 40 Gamma[5/4]^2 Gamma[13/4]) /. Gamma[x_] /; x > 1 :> Product[x - k, {k, IntegerPart[x]}] Gamma[FractionalPart[x]]`